# Expected value of $f(x)=\frac{\sin(A\frac{x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}\frac{\sin(MB\frac{x}{2})}{\sin(B\frac{x}{2})}\cos[\frac{x}{2}[(A-1)+B(M-1)]]$

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, gaussian-integral

I want a closed form/ semi closed form of the expected value of a complicated function.

The function looks like this,

$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin(A \frac{x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})} \frac{\sin(M B\frac{x}{2})}{\sin(B \frac{x}{2})} \cos\Big[\frac{x}{2}[(A - 1) + B(M - 1)]\Big] $$

The terms $A$, $B$, $M$ are constants and integers.

Where, $x$ comes from a Gaussian distribution.

$$ x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma) $$

I want to know what is E[f(x)]. How to approach it?

In integral form, I want to solve the following integral.

$$ E[f(x)] = \int_{-\pi}^{+\pi} \frac{\sin(A \frac{x}{2})}{\sin(\frac{x}{2})} \frac{\sin(M B\frac{x}{2})}{\sin(B \frac{x}{2})} \cos\Big[\frac{x}{2}[(A - 1) + B(M - 1)]\Big] \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{(2\sigma^2)}} dx $$

Mathematica is not able to compute this. Can this integral be performed in the Complex domain?

Comment: My first thoughts were to use complex integration techniques as you say, but given the complexity of the function, it might be unfeasible. It's very possible that you can only solve this numerically.

Comment: Try expanding the $\sin,\cos$ functions in terms of $e^x$ to multiply them with the normal pdf

Comment: I tried to expand it with $e^{ix}$, but there is always a pole in the denominator and it is not easily realized with $e^{ix}$.

Comment: The Gaussian distribution is supported on all of $\mathbb R$. Shouldn't that integral run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Yes I thought so too! However, the integral of these periodic functions don't converge. And, the domain of my $x$ is actually from $-\pi$ to $+\pi$. I thought there can be some hope if the domain is a period of sine or cosine. You can say the $x$ is a truncated Gaussian.